# Error when I try to deploy SSIS package on remote server

Tags: deployment, ssis, sql-server-2016, dts

When I try to deploy SSIS package (2016) from local to remote machine (same version of local machine), 
"Integration Service Deployment Wizard" does not recognize the server and I got this message:

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
>
> ### Failed to connect to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to
>   consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be
>   because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to
>   respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect
>   to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18203;
>   handshake=14372;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)
>
> ------------------------------ The wait operation timed out